# Google Dialogflow showing result from firebase db

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es

I think it's problem of asynchronous things...
How can I resolve this?
below is the code that I want To do, 
I get specific data from db and on for loop, I get data and then show it in suggestion.

I get data very well but when I tested it, my app don't response. 
[image: this image is log message when I execute below function]

```
database.ref('clients/xxxxxx/devices').once('value').then((snap)=>{
  console.log(snap.val());
  var values=snap.val();
  agent.add("this"+conv.body.queryResult.parameters.language);
  for (let val in values) { 
    console.log(val+"////"+values)
    console.log(values[val].title)
    agent.add(new Suggestion(values[val].title));
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with something similar.  Very confusing.  Try putting the return keyword at the front of the first line.  [Here is an explanation.](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/issues/117)